# Prevent save prompt when closing NSWindow

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller, document-based

I have a document-based Cocoa app that uses a secondary `NSWindow` for a preview mode (with `shouldCloseDocument` set to `NO`).

If the document is dirty (edited without saving) and I close the secondary `NSWindow`, a *"Do you want to save the changes made to the document"* prompt appears.

How can I avoid this prompt on the secondary `NSWindow`?

Comment: What if you set the document of the secondary window to nil in windowWillClose delegate method?

Comment: Interesting idea but doesn't work. `windowWillClose` is called after the save prompt appears.

Comment: And so is `windowShouldClose` of NSWindowDelegate and `close` of NSWindow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to do this. I expected to find a `NSWindowDelegate` or `NSWindow` method called before the save prompt but none of the obvious candidates (`windowWillClose`, `close`, `performClose`, `windowShouldClose`) are.

As a workaround, instead of setting `NSWindowController.document` I'm using a custom property to pass the document. With `document` set to `NIL`, the save prompt is not shown anymore.

Answer (score 0):

specifically   you can do this inside your viewController subclass:
make sure delegate is set from the window to the owner class:

```
//-------------------------------------------------------
- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController
{
NSLog (@"windowControllerDidLoadNib");
    aController.document = nil;
    [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];

............. etc.......
```